# configure tableview cell in previous controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have got controller 1 with an imageview, uitextview and button. On button click there is an action to show controller with table view. I need to configure this image view and uitextview.text in my table view, but i don't understand how?

I tried to get access

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customHeader") as CustomHeaderCell
    var controller = PreparePhotoViewController()
    header.headerLabel.text = controller.textView.text//exc BAD ACCESS - textView is an outlet of controller, it is weak
    header.headerPhoto.image = UIImage(named: "heart.png")

    return header
}
```

but it has bad ACCESS exc, cause I think that uitextview with weak property is nil. So any advices how I can do my idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to the view controller you are going to be showing, such as:

`var textToDisplay: String?`

Then, before you push this new view, set that property, e.g.:

```
let viewController = [...]
viewController.textToDisplay = "Hello World"
self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then, in your pushed view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, set the value of the `UILabel`'s `text` property to your new `self.textToDisplay` value.

Hopefully that's the sort of thing you're thinking of?

Comment: this property will be strong? or it will be not nil, after controller will goes to another on? cause i tried something like this and had bad access exc

Comment: Properties in Swift are strong by default, and are only weak if you add `weak` to the property. This is optional, which means it can be nil, and should throw a more descriptive error if the property is nil. Can you edit your question with more code? I don't think it is clear yet where the problem lies

Comment: Ahh, I think I see what you're trying to do. Are you trying to update a label based on the value in a `UITextField` so that when the user types in text that label is changed? The thing that's confusing me is that you're not actually doing anything with your `controller` variable. What is that meant to be doing?

Comment: naah. in my controller1 I have image and text, and i want to set them in controller2(in its tableViewCell)

Comment: I cannot follow what you're saying or what you're trying to acheive. Please post more code, including the code that your question is contained in, and the `PreparePhotoViewController` class

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your approach, but I can see issue in your posted code. You are using wrong dequeue function.
Change `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to `tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier()`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("customHeader") as CustomHeaderCell
    ...
    return header
}
```

And you would probably want to use more accurate name `CustomHeaderView`, not `CustomHeaderCell`.

Comment: your code give exception, it was my first try to do this, I saw tutorials and people are using this method(tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier)

it isn't a question object, so never mind